# SFSafariViewController - How to change the color of the address bar and tab menu

Tags: swiftui, sfsafariviewcontroller

```
How to change the color of the address bar and tab menu in SwiftUi 3.0 using SFSafariViewController. I've tried various things, but that colour doesn't render itself in the simulator.
```

**ContentView**

```
        import SwiftUI
    import SafariServices
    
    struct ContentView: View {
        
        @State private var showSafari: Bool = false
        @State var animate = false
        @State var endSplash = false
        @State var vc = SFSafariViewWrapper(url: URL(string: "https://dc-levo.pewag40.com/login")!)
        
        var body: some View {
            ZStack {
                ZStack {
                    Color("Background")
                        .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .all)
                    
                    Image("splash")
                        .renderingMode(.original)
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .padding(.all)
                    
                    
                }//zstack
                .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .all)
                
            }//zstack
            .ignoresSafeArea(edges: .all)
            .onAppear(perform: {
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.5) {
                    self.showSafari = true
                }
            })
            .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showSafari, content: {
                vc
            })
        }
    }
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
```

How do I modify the code now to display a different color in Safari Web View? The color refers to the color of the address bar and the color of the tab bar located at the bottom of the display.

Comment: Can you share the code of your `SFSafariViewWrapper` View

Comment: ```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import SafariServices


struct SFSafariViewWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    
    
        let url: URL
    
        
        
        func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<Self>) -> SFSafariViewController {
            return SFSafariViewController(url: url)
        }
        
        func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: SFSafariViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SFSafariViewWrapper>) {
            return
        }
    
        }
```

Comment: Check my approach below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `preferredControlTintColor` and/or `preferredControlTintColor` depending on your needs

```
struct SFSafariViewWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    let url: URL

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<Self>) -> SFSafariViewController {
        let sfVC =  SFSafariViewController(url: url)
        sfVC.preferredBarTintColor = .blue // set color to tint the background of the navigation bar and the toolbar.
        sfVC.preferredControlTintColor = .yellow // set the color to tint the control buttons on the navigation bar and the toolbar.
        return sfVC
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: SFSafariViewController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<SFSafariViewWrapper>) {
        return
    }
}
```